# Uploading and processing multiple files in node.js API

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, file, express

I'm new to nodejs and lets say i have to upload several text files in this kind of format to a nodejs endpoint (they could stack to a total of 200mb):

```
AU Olsen, BI
   Lund, NW
   Ellingsen, G
   Hartvigsen, G
PY 2012
ER

AU Ming, X
   Hajid, H
PY 2012
ER
```

What i want to do is to read those files and generate an array of objects that will be returned in the response, something like this:

publications = [{"author":["Olsen, BI", "Lund, NW", "Ellingsen, G", "Hartvigsen, G"],"publicationYear": "2012"},{"author":["Ming, X", "Hajid, H"],"publicationYear":"2012}]

At the moment i try to read all the files that were uploaded in the folder line by line so i can add to the publications variable latter on,the problem is that the publications variable always end up returning empty, looks like anything i do inside the IFS doesn't do anything, its probably an assynchronous callback problem but i have no idea how to fix it.

```
const multer = require ('multer');
const lineReader = require('line-reader');
var fs = require('fs');

const upload = multer({dest: 'uploads/'})
const app = express();
app.use(express.static('public'));

app.post('/uploadAndProcess', upload.array('publications'),(req,res) => {
    var publications = [{}]
    fs.readdir('./uploads', (err, dir)=>{
        for(var i=0; i<dir.length; i++){
            fileName = dir[i];
            lineReader.eachLine('./uploads/'+fileName, function(line) {
                if(line.includes('ER')) {
                    //do something and add to publications variable
                }
                if(line.includes('PY')) {
                    //do something and add to publications variable
                }

            });
        }
      })
    return res.json({pub: publications});
});

app.listen(3001, () => console.log('App is listening...'));
```

Any thoughts? Thank you!

EDIT: Tried with sync readdir and still didnt work :(

```
app.post('/uploadAndProcess', upload.array('publications'),(req,res) => {
   var publications = [{}]
   var files = fs.readdirSync('./uploads');
   for(var file in files) {
       lineReader.eachLine('./uploads/'+files[file], function(line) {
           if(line.includes('ER')) {
               publications.push({'test':'test'})
           }
       });
   };
   return res.json({pub: publications});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are on the right track with the async callback idea. I imagine the response is being sent out before the callback from `fs.readdir` is complete since `fs.readdir` is async and file reading is generally an expensive operation. Try using the `fs.readdirSync` function to process these synchronously and see if it works! Here's a link to the [Node documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdirsync_path_options) to get you started.

Comment: unfortunately that didn't work aswell (see edited post), any thoughts?

Comment: What `lineReader` are you using? Is `lineReader.eachLine` also async? `readdirSync` returns a list of strings representing the filename so `'./uploads/'+files[file]` looks suspicious. Probably just need `'./uploads/'+file`.